# Are all $\mathbf{P^1}$-fibrations projective bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fiber-bundles, birational-geometry

Maybe there is a very simple answer to my question or a counterexample - I don't see it:
Let $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow C$ be a flat, smooth family with fibres $\cong \mathbf{P^1}$  of dim $2$ over a smooth projective base $C$ (maybe just $\mathbf{P}^1 $).
Is then necessarily $\mathcal{X}$ isomorphic to $\mathbf{P}(\mathcal{E})$ for a rank $2$-bundle on $C$? The only fibrations I know with these properties are the Hirzebruch surfaces $\mathbf{F}_n=\mathbf{P}(\mathcal{O}\oplus\mathcal{O}(n))$, who are obviously projective bundles, so is this true more generally? Thank you

Comment: Differential point of view: the automorphism group of the projective line is $PGL_2$. Taking local trivializations you get a family of transition functions, and we need to check the cocycle condition.

Comment: thank you, that is true! But that doesn't necessarily glue to a global bundle, at least I don't see how that helps answering the question...?

Comment: I just wanted to say that the answer is yes iff the Brauer group of $C$ is trivial.

Comment: @DamianRössler It seems more accurate to me to say that this is true if and only if $\mathrm{Br}(C)[2]$ is trivial (or at least this implies the condition the OP asked about).

Comment: @Alex Youcis. Yes, correct, I was thinking of the existence of Severi-Brauer schemes of any relative dimension, not just relative dimension one.

Comment: thank you guys, are you here talking about the fact that obstructions from $GL_n$ to $PGL_n$ come from a class in $H^2(\mathbf{C}^\times)$? So maybe this question shouldn't have been closed?